# Capturing multiple images using camera2api makes the preview pause for a moment while taking the picture

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using camera2 api for my custom camera app and I am able to successfully take a pic and save it. Now, when trying to take multiple images without the user intervention the preview get's struck or paused for a moment. How do I solve this? So basically taking the picture should happen in the background without obstructing the preview. Below is my code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.media.ExifInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;




public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();



    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    Size largest;

    public static Response response1;

    float Sx, Sy, Ix, Iy;
    public float[] pixelArrayy;
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap;
    public static String ovalPixelsJsonArrayString1;
    Bitmap croppedBitmap;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gesture1_cam_camera2);

        //Get startTime for Gesture1Cam
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Log.e("shashankStart", String.valueOf(start));

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Gesture1CamCamera2Activity.this);

        //Get screen pixels
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        Sx = metrics.widthPixels;
        Sy = metrics.heightPixels;

        //  Log.e("Sx and Sy", Sx + ", " + Sy);


        textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture_gesture1Cam2);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        takePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_takepicture_gesture1Cam2);
        assert takePictureButton != null;



        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                takePicture();
                // this code will be executed after 2 seconds
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new
            TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                    //open your camera here
                    openCamera();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int
                        width, int height) {
                    // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
                }

                @Override

                public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                }
            };

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new
            CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                    //This is called when the camera is open
                    // Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
                    cameraDevice = camera;
                    createCameraPreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                    cameraDevice.close();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    cameraDevice.close();
                    cameraDevice = null;
                }
            };

    protected void startBackgroundThread() {

        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {

        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void takePicture() {

        if (null == cameraDevice) {

            // Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        try {

            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            final File file = getOutputMediaFile();
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, JSONException {

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);





                    //Get orientation
                    InputStream io = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                    ExifInterface exif = null;

                    try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(io);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                    // Log.e("orientation", String.valueOf(orientation));

                    //Get rotated bitmap
                    bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
                    //
                    Ix = bitmap.getWidth();
                    Iy = bitmap.getHeight();






                    try {

                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();

                        // Log.e("Image1", "Saved");
                        imageSavedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        imageSaveTime = String.valueOf(imageSavedTime - takePic);
                        Log.e("shashank_SaveImageTime", imageSaveTime);

                        takePicture();


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    // Toast.makeText(Gesture1CamCamera2Activity.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int rotatedPreviewWidth = textureView.getWidth();
            int rotatedPreviewHeight = textureView.getHeight();
            int maxPreviewWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
            int maxPreviewHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            largest = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)), new CompareSizesByArea());

            imageDimension = Utils.chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                    maxPreviewHeight, largest);

            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(Gesture1CamCamera2Activity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        // Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = "1";
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Gesture1CamCamera2Activity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }

    protected void updatePreview() {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            // Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(Gesture1CamCamera2Activity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {

            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }

    }

    public File getOutputMediaFile() {

        final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

        File mediaStorageDir =
                new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "GesturesAppGes1");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("shanksPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + username + "_deltaTime1_" + deltaTime1 + "_deltaTime2_" + deltaTime2 + ".jpg");

        path1 = file.getPath();

        return file;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a ImageReader with a maximum JPEG buffer of only 2 images:

```
ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
```

If the recevied [Image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image) objects aren't closed in time, then the [onImageAvailable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener.html#onImageAvailable(android.media.ImageReader)) callback will stall until these are closed, when the onImageAvailable doesn't have more free images in its buffer the preview will freeze.

To solve it increase the maxImages to a few more in the [ImageReader.newInstance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). Take into account that if you put a high number and the **Image** objects aren't closed in time, you may run out of memory.

Besides the maxImages buffer, something else which may affect performance, is that you are creating a byte buffer for each JPEG right in onImageAvailable callback. A better approach would be to pass the Image objects to a separate saving background thread. Though, this path requires a bit more of work as you need to do some extra steps to ensure that the Image objects aren't released before they get saved, which may happen if the camera device gets closed. See the [Camera2Raw](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw) sample for this approach.